# Matching unknown custom data attributes?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Is there a way to match elements that has unknown custom data attributes?
By unknown I mean that an element may look like this:

```
<div data-unknown="foo"></div>
```

or

```
<td data-someOtherCustomDataAttribute="bar"></td>
```

and I would like to match all elements that has a data-* attribute. That is, both the *div* and the *td* tag should be matched.
I know how to match on values, but not on the attributes themselves.

Any clues?

Comment: What's the purpose of selecting all elements that have a data-* attribute? Data attributes aren't inherently related to one another, save for the fact that they all start with "data-".

Comment: did you find an acceptable solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

There is no tool for this in CSS itself.

There is only one way how you can select elements by presence of an attribute: `selector[attribute]`. And there is no way to define some pattern of how attribute looks (for example regexp or something like that), so you may only just set attribute name.

Comment: I think that there is a tool for it, see my answer below.

Comment: @Speransky Danil, it was me who downvoted this answer as a) not knowledgeable (or completely wrong) and b) for looking more like a comment than an answer.

Comment: It could be some more elaborate - e.g. mentioning that the attribute selector doesn't allow wildcards (such as `[data-*]`) and *that's* why it doesn't work with CSS.

Comment: Why include the selector part? your example will limit the selection: `div[data-foo]` will select only `div`s and if there are `td` with the `data-foo` - they will not be matched

Answer (score 1):

There is a special class of selectors. They are called "[attribute selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#attribute-selectors)"
In the [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11709257/1144057) a similar solution was suggested, but it needed a value, whereas mine - doesn't :)

It should be something like this:

```
[data-unknown]{
    color: red;
}
```

Basically - you repeat the whole attribute, be it `data-unknown` or `data-anything_you_want`.

A live example of it can be seen here: http://jsfiddle.net/skip405/2vhBj/

Comment: See my comments on starbeamrainbowlabs' answer, except this time, as you say the value isn't relevant.

Comment: Also, attribute selectors are supported in IE7+; you should not need Selectivizr to polyfill them.

Comment: @BoltClock, yes, you are right saying that they are supported, it's not `[data^=attr]`. Sorry about that :) I edited the answer. As for the whole *question-thing* - I agree that it's kinda strange to select all the elements *altogether* - but my answer is closer imho to styling such elements than starbeamrainbowlabs's answer... not to mention the answer provided by Speransky Danil. Cos it answers the question `Can they be matched **somehow**?` Even if he has to write all the attributes like so - `[data-foo], [data-bar], [data-somethingelse] { styles }`

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
div[attribute=value]
{
    /*css here...*/
}
```

It is very important that there are no spaces in the selector.

Haven't tested whether it will work for unknown attributes though. It should do, because css can style XML as well.

Comment: That requires the attribute name (and value) to be known, but to be fair, I don't really see the point in selecting elements by unknown attribute names either...

Comment: If you do not know what the attribute is, then how can you select it?

Comment: That's what I'm wondering too. The question is clear in writing, but its premise seems nonsensical.

Answer (score -1):

If you're using HTML5's data- attributes, and you have a browser supporting HTML5 JavaScript's `dataset` element property, you can select dynamically (I'm using jQuery to shorten the example):

```
$('.contains-data').each( function() {
    $(this).dataset().each( function (key, value) {
        if (value != '') { // put your "selector" criteria here
             alert(key + ': ' + value);
        }
    }
});
```

You can accomplish the same without jQuery with a little more work to initially select all page elements having class "contains-data".

This strategy does require use of JavaScript, so YMMV.

See [HTML5 Custom Data Attributes (data-*): Using data- attributes with JavaScript](http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/) for more information.